# Does Services module still need a key

Tags: drupal, drupal-services

I'm reading a book that suggests that you try to configure the Services module, you should see 3 tabs: `Browse`, `Settings`, and `Keys`. I'm working with the latest release and all I see is `Browse` and `Settings`. Anyone knows what happened to the `Keys` tab? Has the module logic changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable Key Authentication within Services, Keys will present itself.

Comment: Looks like I had to enable the `Key Authentication` module in addition to the `Services` module. That step was missed in the tutorial I'm following.

Comment: Is key authentication unsupported in version 3? I can't find any authentication options or included modules